# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'UIManager.AndroidTextInput.Constants')

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-modal

I'm currently working on both the Android and iOS version using react-native but I'm getting the following error arise on the iOS version:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'UIManager.AndroidTextInput.Constants')

[image: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'UIManager.AndroidTextInput.Constants')]

Answer (score 0):

... Basically, there was a bad equality checker of:

`if (Platform.OS = 'android') { ...`

for

```
componentDidMount() {  
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackOnOverlay);
    }
```

Which resulted in the event listener being added for the android back button in the iOS app. The above errors were showing as a result of this it seems. Never assume the error message is the error as such.